# Non-EU national with Irish residence permit. Can I visit UK?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, ireland

I am an Indian national with Irish residence permit.

> Can I visit the UK without visa?

I plan to visit the London for 1 week.

I know that Irish citizens can visit UK without any restrictions, but what about Non-EU nationals holding valid residence permit issued by irish authorities?

I just learned that Ireland neither part of UK, nor in Schengen zone.

Comment: The Republic of Ireland is not part of the UK; Northern Ireland is. Your question is just fine without asking about that, however. It just seems to confuse things. You must be aware of the answer, or you wouldn't have posted this on the first place.

Comment: @pbu Out of curiosity what made you think the Republic of Ireland was part of the United Kingdom?

Comment: @davidb it's quite common to confuse Great Britain and the United Kingdom, and Northern Ireland and the Republic of Ireland

Comment: Thats right @davidb. Sorry, Ireland visa agreements is always confusing to us Asians, I just learned that Ireland is not a part of schengen, neither UK.